# Error when create UserFactory

Tags: laravel

In my UserFactory.php I have

```
$factory->define(App\Gear::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'barcode' => $faker->isbn13,
]; });
```

I just want to execute in a 'barcode' column. But when I run `php aritsan tinker` 
I get an error message: `General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value`. But in database field 'name' i had value in column 'name'. What should I do to be able to randomly number the barcode in the `barcode` column

Thanks

Comment: you must add default value to database 'name' column

Answer (score 1):

A factory is used for generating new models, usually for testing purposes. You are getting this error because you are attempting to create a user with only a barcode property.

If you want to use a factory to generate users and persist them to the database then you will need to provide all of the required fields.

```
$factory->define(App\Gear::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        // plus any additional required fields
        'barcode' => $faker->isbn13,
    ]; 
});
```

If you want to update existing users with a property you will need to create a database migration.